# Private member declared in other class

Tags: c++, class, attributes, stream, private

I'm programming my first big "class" in a c++ program (it deals with I/O stream) and I think I understood the concepts of object, methods and attributes.
Though I guess I still don't get all the rights of the encapsulation notion,
because I want my class called File to have

- a name (the path of the file),
- a reading stream, and
- a writing stream

as attributes,

and also its first method to actually get the "writing stream" attribute of the File object...

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class File {
public:
    File(const char path[]) : m_filePath(path) {}; // Constructor
    File(std::string path) : m_filePath(path) {}; // Constructor overloaded
    ~File(); // Destructor
    static std::ofstream getOfstream(){ // will get the private parameter std::ofStream of the object File
        return m_fileOStream;
    };
private:
    std::string m_filePath; // const char *m_filePath[]
    std::ofstream m_fileOStream;
    std::ifstream m_fileIStream;
};
```

But I get the error:

> Error 4 error C2248: 'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ios' :
>   cannot access private member declared in class
>   'std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits>' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 10.0\vc\include\fstream 1116

reporting me to the following part of fstream.cc :

```
private:
    _Myfb _Filebuffer;  // the file buffer
    };
```

Could you then help me to fix this and be able to use a stream as parameter of my class please? I have tried to return a reference instead of the stream itself, but I'm gonna need some help with that as well (doesn't work either...).
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should be getting an error in the fact that you're trying to access an instance member from a static member function. What happens when you call it like `File::getOfstream()`?

Comment: Maybe you should consider returning a *reference* to the std::ofstream instead of a copy?

Comment: Is that really the first error message?  I would expect something about a (possibly implicit) copy constructor.

Comment: Unrelated to your error: you don't need the 2 constructor overloads, only the one taking `std::string` should suffice since `std::string` has a non-`explicit` constructor that takes a `const char *`. So if you call the File constructor with a `const char *` argument the compiler will perform an implicit conversion to `std::string`

Comment: Indeed, change made. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
static std::ofstream getOfstream(){ // will get the private parameter std::ofStream of the object File
        return m_fileOStream;
    };
```

to

```
// remove static and make instance method returning a reference
// to avoid the copy constructor call of std::ofstream
std::ostream& getOfstream(){ return m_fileOStream; }
```

Comment: Thanks, now how am I suppose to call it as a function parameter? I always get this error:  
a reference of type "std::ofstream &" (not const-qualified) cannot
be initialized with a value of type "std::ostream"

Comment: change the return param to std::ofstream:

std::ofstream& getOfstream(){ return m_fileOStream; }

Comment: Still not... I use it in the method: 
_int File::sendErrorOpeningStream(std::string ifstream_ofstream, **std::ofstream outputFile**, char *wd)_

---

I then come up with : 
_error C2664: 'File::sendErrorOpeningStream' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::ostream' to 'std::ofstream'_

Answer (score 1):

Each class has three section, So suppose the following class:

```
class Example{

public:
   void setTime(int time);
   int getTime() const;
private:
 int time;
protected:
bool ourAttrib;

}
```

You see public, private and protected words, yes, They explain encapsulation , When you can use private for method or attributes, just members can use it.But when you use public, everbody use it.Now protected: when you a class derived from this class, derived class can use protected and inherited them.

Comment: How about I have "public", "private", "protected" and then "public" again, yes — do I have four section now, yes?

Comment: Oh  no, You should 3 section: pubclic, private, protected